# Set color of a textbox programatically in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, background, textbox

In trying to set the color of a text box in my WPF application I did

[image]

Why do I get that error ?

And how to rectify it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's telling you right in the error. The `Background` property is of type `System.Windows.Media.Brush`, not `System.Windows.Media.Color`, so you can't assign a `Color` to it.

Pass a `Brush` into your method instead of a `Color`, and assign that to the `Background` property.

```
public void addToStackPanel(string argBuiltAlarm, Brush brush)
{
    ...
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox { Background = brush };
    ...
```

Comment: Alternatively, a Brush can be created from the given color: `Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(color)`

Comment: Solved.Thanks.and @elgonzo , you are completely right too(I used your solution )

Answer (score -1):

```
textBox1.Background = Brushes.Blue;
textBox1.Foreground = Brushes.Yellow;
```

You can do like this.